# Why is Lenovo P620 slow when compiling MSVC 2013 C++ ARM project on M.2 drive?

Tags: ssd, ramdisk, m.2, visual-c++, threadripper

**Update [Jan 20, 2021]**: I reported a drop in the PCIe SSD performance -- this was user error and I posted correction below. I opened a new question regarding [how to verify compiler performance](https://superuser.com/questions/1619353/how-to-measure-performance-of-visual-studio-compiler) and will continue to update this post as I learn more.

I have a 32GB RAM Lenovo P620 compiling a Visual Studio 2013 project and do not understand why compiling is slow when project is on a WDC SN730 M.2 drive whereas when compiling code on a RAM drive is 2.3X faster. Based on experience with a similar AMD 5950X system, I expect much less performance difference. Compiling code on a RAM drive yields expected performance; but when project is on a M.2 SSD the compile performance is way too slow.

This is an ARM project being build with Visual Studio 2013. The Microsoft ARM compiler is actually a Visual Studio 2012 compiler as it is the only MS compiler that supports compiling ARM code for the WEC2013 operating system.

Specs for the Lenovo P620 system:

- AMD Threadripper PRO 3955WX Processor (3.9 GHz, up to 4.3 GHz Max Boost, 32 Threads)
- 32 GB RAM in four 3200 MHz RDIMMs, 59 GBps bandwidth
- 512 GB WDC SN730 M.2 SSD
- Windows 10 Pro
- MS Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 v12,0.40629 Update 5 with Application Builder For Windows Embedded Compact 2013
- Runs on office domain
- compile time on M.2: 150 seconds (2.3 times RAM drive compile time)
- compile time on 2 GB RAM drive: 65 seconds

Specs for comparison 5950X system:

- AMD Ryzen 5950X Processor (3.4 GHz, up to 4.9 GHz Max Boost, 32 Threads)
- 64 GB RAM in four 3600 MHz DIMMs, 41 GBps bandwidth
- 960 GB Samsung 960 Pro M.2 SSD
- Windows 10 Pro
- Not on office domain
- MS Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 v12,0.40629 Update 5 with Application Builder For Windows Embedded Compact 2013
- compile time on M.2: 90 seconds (1.4 times RAM drive compile time)
- compile time on 2 GB RAM drive: 62 seconds

The performance is similar for compiling on RAM disk but the P620 takes about 2.3X longer when compiling the same project on the M.2 SSD instead of the RAM drive -- *1.6X longer than the 5950X system also compiling the same project on a M.2 SSD!* The compile speed on M.2 should be close to RAM drive speed because building the C++ project benefits from OS-level drive caching and this is what I've seen consistently on other systems; **taking 2.3X longer seems as though the Windows drive cache is not effective**.

To find the root of the performance problem, I added more memory to the P620, disabled antivirus, waited 20 minutes after boot before compiling. I even replaced the M.2 drive with a Samsung 980 Pro and the performance remained almost the same even though SiSoft Sandra showed the 980 Pro was 2X faster than the SN730 at 6.4 GBps.

Actually, when anti-virus was disabled both M.2 and RAM drive performance improved by about 7 seconds. But compiling in 144 seconds on the M.2 is just wrong when the AMD 5950X system does it in 90 seconds with an SSD that is half as fast.

I tested on a third system, a 16 GB i7 notebook computer with 12 logical cores -- compiling on its SSD took 189 seconds. This number is proportional to the 32-logical core 5950X system's M.2 performance but only 40 seconds slower than the P620 that has 2.5X more logical cores. I did not try the RAM disk on the notebook.

Any idea what I can check to identify the cause of the slow M.2 compiles on the P620?

Updates:

- Verified via Device Manager that write-caching is enabled for M.2 SSD
- Disabled Windows file indexing for project folder -- no significant improvement
- Deleted temp files (*.suo, *.sdf, *.user) that were copied over with project folder ([SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617670/why-is-visual-studio-2013-very-slow)) -- no difference
- Setting project on M.2 to store temporary files (OBJs) on RAM drive: 155 secs compile time
- Setting project on RAM drive to store temporary files on M.2 SSD: 65 secs copmpile time, **indicating read speed on M.2 is causing problem**
- Ran Samsung Magician benchmark and SiSoft Sandra benchmark on PCIe M.2; both indicate expected bandwidth
- SSD Performance verified using ATTO benchmark utility *is consistent with product reviews*.

  - **Update [Jan 20, 2021]**: I previously reported a huge performance drop in the PCIe Gen 4 drive. I used an outdated version of ATTO benchmark utility. Benchmarking using latest version of ATTO benchmark utility showed same performance as in product reviews of drive.

Comment: Sounds like your workload prefers faster cores over more cores.

Comment: Compiling in RAM drive shows a near linear performance increase as the number of cores increases. Prior to the 5950X I used an AMD 3900X and the jump from 24 logical cores to 32 logical cores improved compile time about 30% with either M.2 or RAM drive. The Lenovo P620 is a new system and is the only machine that compiles slow when project is on M.2. Seeing the i7 notebook compile in line with the performance of AMD 3900X and the 5950X was a revelation that M.2 performance is off on the Lenovo.

Compiling a project on a fast drive should make little difference due to caching at OS level.