# How to measure performance of Visual Studio compiler?

Tags: performance, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-c++, threadripper

**How to measure performance of Visual Studio compiler when compiling C++ project?**

I am investigating slow compiles on an AMD 3955WX (ThreadRipper Pro) system compared to an AMD 5950X (Zen 3) system.

The way I test compile performance is I set Visual Studio to log compile time and I compile a 400K-line C++ project and compare the elapsed time. I cannot share the source code so no one can confirm my findings.

**How to test compile speed of Visual Studio C++ compiler?**

This is Windows, so I don't think compiling the Linux kernel is an option... or is it? I would like to get results in a minute or so... 30 minutes compile-time will suck.

Is there a open source project that people compile *on Windows* to evaluate compile times?

Is there a better way to test compile time performance?

Comment: when you say slow compiles, how slow are we talking? your big bottleneck will generally be IO related to many small files. do you have SSD storage and sufficient free RAM? the diff in CPU is definitely not the issue.

Comment: Compile in 150s (3955WX: 32 GB, 4-channel 3200 MHz RDIMM [59 GBps bandwidth]). 
Compile in 90s (5950X: 64 GB, 2-channel 3600 MHz DIMM [41 GBps bandwidth]).
Compiling in RAM drive: 64 and 62 secs. Ruled out a bad compiler install by cloning the 5950X SSD, put in 3955WX system & updated drivers -- got same 150 sec compile time. Bad drivers for 3955WX motherboard? The chipset for 3955WX is new, but 150 secs vs 90 secs??? Drives in all tests are Samsung Pro M.2 SSDs with lots of space. Used SiSoft Sandra to check RAM bandwidth. Running only compiler and TaskMan during tests... no browsers open.

Comment: the ram drive figures definitely indicate an IO bottleneck. 400MHz on the ram freq isn't going to have that kind of impact, and your bandwidth is fine. the most meaningful diff is the 32 vs 64GB, but I do find it hard to believe that your compile could come close to using 32GB in the first place.

Comment: I dropped 5950X RAM to 32GB and got same 90s results as before (3955WX compile time is 150s w/ 32GB). For tests, I only load IDE so memory footprint is minimal; RAM quantity is not a problem. With 32 GB, TaskMan shows over 16GB available at end of compile.

Comment: I asked about a standard "compilation performance" project so others can repeat my test. I used a closed-source project on multiple systems; the only inconsistency is the Lenovo P620 ThreadRipper Pro. With few cores, the CPU is a bottleneck and compiling on RAM drive matches SSD compile times. An old 6-core Xeon yields 1% faster RAM compile, a 6-core 3600X has 10% faster RAM compile times, a 12-core 3900X has 25% faster RAM compile times. The 16-core 5950X compiles RAM drive project 45% faster. The ThreadRipper Pro system RAM compile is spot-on, but SSD compile is slower than 12-core 3900X.

Comment: I'm questioning whether your question is practical in nature. I know its a pain to deal with a 120+ second compile time, but is your goal to get the two boxes to compile in the same time, cause your devs are complaining, or is this more academic in nature? also, its not really clear that your compiler is able to make good use of multithreading for this particular job, and the Ram Disk test is 33% better than M.2/Sata even on your faster system (and 150% better for the slower one), that says that your bottleneck is IO any way you slice it. don't focus so much on CPU.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118765/discussion-between-pixelgrease-and-frank-thomas).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question is to use the vcperf tool as outlined here:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/finding-build-bottlenecks-with-cpp-build-insights/

On the first step you only need to do 1 & 2. The rest of the article other than that seems to hit the key points.

And useful tip is to please make sure the /MP flag is enabled for the projects in question. FOR SOME REASON IT IS NOT ENABLED BY DEFAULT. This flag is used to enable Multi-Processing compilation.

Comment: Windows Performance Analyzer provides in-depth build statistics and may help me determine the root cause. However, I still don't have a generic test that allows C++ developers outside my company to verify the performance issue -- I am unable to compile the referenced vcperf project due to "project references NuGet package(s) that are missing" errors that I could not resolve in less than an hour.

Comment: Thanks for linking to the article that contains the answer to this question. However, for the benefit of the encyclopedic value of this website, would you be able to summarize the key points of the article in your answer?